# How to let the user readjust and crop the image as in viber and fb app

Tags: codenameone

How can I let users re-adjust and crop the image as in viber or fb app so that the image uploaded are proportionally scaled to the size we wanted.

Code:

```
profileImg.addActionListener((e) -> {
    Display.getInstance().openGallery(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            try {
                if (evt == null) {
//                            System.out.println("user cancelled");
                    return;
                }
                profileImgpath = (String) evt.getSource();

                Image i = Image.createImage(profileImgpath);
                Image profileImgg = i.scaledWidth(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth() / 3);
                profileImg.getParent().revalidate();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, Display.GALLERY_IMAGE);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to build your own component to do that.  After you retrieve the image from the gallery, you would display the image in your widget, which would allow users to do pinch zoom, and move the photo, etc...

I don't have an example on hand to do this, as it's a pretty specific component you need to build. There is lots of documentation in the CN1 website and developer guide on building custom components, and handling user interaction (e.g. pressing, dragging, etc...).